# DataContractSerializer serializes interface properties as System.Object / anyType

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

In an application I have the following interface / implementation structure:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  IMyOtherInterface InstanceOfMyOtherInterface { get; }
}

public interface IMyOtherInterface
{
  string SomeValue { get; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "MyInterfaceImplementation", Namespace = "")]
public class MyInterfaceImplementation : IMyInterface
{
  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false), XmlAttribute(Namespace = "")]
  public IMyOtherInterface InstanceOfMyOtherInterface { get; private set; }

  public MyInterfaceImplementation()
  {
    this.InstanceOfMyOtherInterface = new MyOtherInterfaceImplementation("Hello World");
  }
}

[DataContract(Name = "MyOtherInterfaceImplementation", Namespace = "")]
public class MyOtherInterfaceImplementation : IMyOtherInterface
{
  [DataMember]
  public string SomeValue { get; private set; }

  public MyOtherInterfaceImplementation(string value)
  {
    this.SomeValue = value; 
  }
}
```

Now whenever I use a .Net DataContractSerializer to serialize this (in my case into a string) like this:

```
var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyInterfaceImplementation));
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
{
  dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, this);
}
var stringValue = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

the resulting xml looks pretty much like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<z:anyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" i:type="MyInterfaceImplementation" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  <InstanceOfMyOtherInterface xmlns="" i:type="InstanceOfMyOtherInterface">
    <SomeValue>Hello World</SomeValue>
  </InstanceOfMyOtherInterface>
</z:anyType>
```

These *anyType*s seem to come from the datacontractserializer's serializing the MyInterfaceImplementation instance as System.Object, likewise with other interface properties.

If I used concrete types in my interface and its implementation(s) like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  MyOtherInterface InstanceOfMyOtherInterface { get; }
}
```

.. it works 'fine' as in - the datacontractserializer does create

```
<MyInterfaceImplementation>...</MyInterfaceImplementation>
```

...nodes instead of the z:anyType ones but I do not want / can't change my interfaces' properties. Is there any way to control or aid the data contract serializer in such cases?

Comment: It's not usually useful to serialize interface instances. How would you deserialize them? Into which class?

Comment: @John, that's a good point, didn't think about it that way.. and that's why the datacontractserializer probably adds the type="..." attribute and defaults to System.Object kind of serialization. However the question remains, can I modify the later & if so what would I have to do aid in the deserialization scenario?

Comment: There is nothing you can do to deserialize an interface. Which class would you create? How would you even describe the interface in the WSDL? There's no such concept.